# Remove comma from csv

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-replace

I want to remove comma `(,)` From CSV.
String is as below.

```
10 ft.,11 ft. [Add $37.49],12 ft. [Add $74.98],13 ft. [Add $112.48],14 ft. [Add $149.97],15 ft. [Add $187.46],16 ft. [Add $224.95],17 ft. [Add $262.44],18 ft. [Add $299.94],19 ft. [Add $337.43],20 ft. [Add $374.92],25 ft. [Add $562.38],30 ft. [Add $749.84],35 ft. [Add $937.30],40 ft. [Add $1,124.76]
```

I want to remove decimal point . from price.

```
$1,124.76
```

So final out must be:

```
10 ft.,11 ft. [Add $37.49],12 ft. [Add $74.98],13 ft. [Add $112.48],14 ft. [Add $149.97],15 ft. [Add $187.46],16 ft. [Add $224.95],17 ft. [Add $262.44],18 ft. [Add $299.94],19 ft. [Add $337.43],20 ft. [Add $374.92],25 ft. [Add $562.38],30 ft. [Add $749.84],35 ft. [Add $937.30],40 ft. [Add $1124.76]
```

Comment: `\[[^,\]]*\K,` replace with nothing

Comment: output you mentioned is same as your input

Comment: @TousifKhan look the last price

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
(\$\d+),(\d+)(?=\.\d+\])
```

with

```
$1$2
```

[Demo and some explanations](https://regex101.com/r/VkPgtT/1)

Comment: this seems correct answer

Answer (score 0):

This approaching can remove all commas on your lines

```
<?php 
$string = "SET YOUR LINE";
echo preg_replace ( "/\$\d+,\d+/" , "" , $string );
?>
```